# store read bytes to unsigned long array

Tags: c++, casting, ifstream

I would like to use `istream::read`, with an `unsigned long` array. I expect the result to be as if I was using a `char` array but the result would be stored in an `unsigned long`.

example:

```
std::ifstream foo("filename.txt", std::ios::binary);
//supose foo is 0x00 0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04 ...
unsigned long bar[256];
foo.read((char*)(&bar), 256); //bar[0] = 0x00, bar[1] = 0x01 ...
//each bytes of foo would be store in one item of bar.
```

but this obviously doesn't work because `unsigned long` and `char` are stored differently. I know that I can create a temporary `char` array that would be casted in `unsigned long *`, but I want to use directly the `unsigned long` array.

doest any body knows how I can make this work, **without creating a temporary char array**.

**EDIT**

with @Sam Varshavchik suggestion, I wrote following code:

```
ifstream file("filename;txt", ios::in | ios::binary);

unsigned long buffer[256];
for(unsigned i = 0; i < 256; ++i){
    file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer + i), sizeof(char));
}
```

and it works

Comment: Have you tried `foo.read((char*)(&bar), 256 * sizeof(unsigned long));`?

Comment: The size you pass to `read` is the size in *bytes*, not elements.

Comment: Also please use `reinterpret_cast<char*>(bar)` instead of the C-style cast you currently have. C-style casts are generally a sign that you're doing something wrong. In this case it isn't, but better get into the good habits of using the C++-specific casts constructs.

Comment: Pointer (`char*`) arguments to functions like the stream `read` and `write` are one of the few places where `reinterpret_cast` is acceptable in modern C++. But the evil, C-style cast is still evil.

Comment: @user17732522 I would like bar[0] = 0x00, bar[1] = 0x01 ... and so on.

Comment: Read from the stream, character by character, and store each character in each `unsigned long`? Is that what you're asking? If so, there is no built-in function that does this for you, you must implement this logic yourself. There are very, very few magic buttons in C++ that only need to be located and pushed, to make everything happen, and this isn't one of them. In all other cases code must be written and debugged.

Comment: So you want to interpret each byte as a separate long? That's not possible without copying each byte individually into a long (i.e. using a temporary char array)

Comment: @Kevin You don't need a temporary character **array**; just a temporary (single) `char` - inside a loop that then copies that into the `unsigned long` array elements.

Comment: The file is a stream of *bytes*, not a stream of *longs*.You can't read a single byte into a long like that.

Comment: OK, so now the question is why "_but I want to use directly the unsigned long array._" is important?

Comment: @user17732522 because It's too long (wordy).

Comment: @tony_merguez Then it can't be done without some intermediate storage. Like many newbies it seems you believe in the magical power of casting. I'm afraid there is no cast that is going to help you here.

Comment: Also, is this to read an existing file with a specific (and well-documented) binary format? Or is the file-format something you have control over (you also make the code writing to the file)? If you have control over the format, then *please* don't use binary files. Text-files are so much better, and will save you so many problems.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I know what I am doing, but there is too much context to explain.

Comment: I just don't understand why such a basic cast doesn't exist in the stl

Comment: Because you can't cast it. An `unsigned long` takes maybe 8 bytes and a `char` takes 1 byte. It will never be in the library. It can't be done.

Comment: @tony_merguez The problem is that `read` reads from a file to a contiguous sequence of bytes. Your requirement is to read to a non-contiguous sequence (i.e. read one byte per long). No cast can make a fundamental difference to the way `read` operates.

Comment: @john I still want to read contiguously, but store it non contiguously.

Comment: @tony_merguez Exactly, that's the problem, `read` stores contiguously, that's just the way it works.

Comment: Do you need to write to that array later on?

Comment: The title of this question presents as an XY problem.  The actual goal is that there is a file full of (unsigned?) 8-bit integers and you want to read them into an array of unsigned 32-bit integers.  Your solution evaluation criteria seem to be eliminating "wordiness" (using economical syntax?) and avoiding a temporary array (syntactically? or physically?)  Seeking a specific solution by pre-committing to a technique that that may not do the job (fstream::read and cast) is the definition of an XY problem.  Remove the word _cast_ from the title.

Comment: @tony_merguez *This doesn't give the expected result*. That's probably because of endianness. Don't fake it, if you are reading a byte then read it into a char variable (or unsigned char), then assign the char variable to your long array.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer + i), sizeof(char));
```

try this:

```
char out{};
file.read(&out, sizeof(char));
// make sure your data is never negative
buffer[i] = static_cast<unsigned long>(out);
```

The reason is that writing a char to a long involves more that just setting one of its bytes. That more work (e.g. nulling the other bytes, respecting endianness, and so forth) is done by the explicit upcast by C++.